# Calculate the percentage of polygon inside the buffer in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, geospatial, postgis, spatial-query

I have a table named Operation with multiple points as geom and I have created a buffer of 100m and added as a new column to the same table. I have another table named Residential which has multiple polygons, the goal is to find the percentage of polygons are inside each buffer and add it as a column in the Operation table. I am not sure how to proceed with this.

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn ('public','operations','buffer',4326,'POLYGON',2);
UPDATE operations SET buffer = ST_Buffer(geom::geography,100)::geometry;

ALTER TABLE operations ADD COLUMN pts int;

UPDATE operations o 
SET pts = (SELECT count(*) FROM supermarket s
           WHERE ST_Contains(o.buffer,s.geom));
```

I have done till this, the following lines are not suited to get the percentage. How to approach this.

```
    ALTER TABLE public."Operation" ADD COLUMN res_percent double precision;
UPDATE public."Operation"  
SELECT      
  ST_Intersection(ST_MakeValid(r.geom),o.buffer) AS intersection,   
  ST_Area(ST_Intersection(ST_MakeValid(r.geom),o.buffer))/ST_Area(r.geom)*100)) 
FROM public."Residential" r, public."Operation" o 
WHERE ST_Intersects(o.buffer,ST_MakeValid(r.geom));
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=fc82eef3ce0b0af4118a993ca50ddcb8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ST_Area`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Area.html) to get the area of your polygons, extract the area of their intersection using [`ST_Intersection`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html), then finally use both intersection area and polygons area to calculate the overlap proportion.

##### Example

Given two overlapping polygons,`p1` and `p2`, in a table called `t` :

[image]

We can use `ST_Intersection` to get the intersection of both polygons:

```
SELECT ST_Intersection(p1,p2) FROM t;
```

[image]

Now we can use `ST_Area` to calculate the area of this intersection:

```
SELECT ST_Area(ST_Intersection(p1,p2)) FROM t;

    st_area     
----------------
 601950.9523732
(1 row)
```

So, using `ST_Area` in both intersection and polygons you are able to calculate which percentage of a polygon overlaps with another, e.g.

```
SELECT 
  ST_Area(ST_Intersection(p1,p2))/ST_Area(p2)*100 AS perc_p2, 
  ST_Area(ST_Intersection(p1,p2))/ST_Area(p1)*100 AS perc_p1
FROM t;

     perc_p2      |     perc_p1      
------------------+------------------
 30.0839473794556 | 37.9061430278047
(1 row)
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9b1c802b50460c7c7ab734ff936d73cf)

Given your description your query should look somewhat like this:

```
SELECT   
  ST_Intersection(r.geom,o.buffer) AS intersection,
  ST_Area(ST_Intersection(r.geom,o.buffer))/ST_Area(r.geom)*100
FROM residential r, operations o
WHERE ST_Intersects(o.buffer,r.geom);
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried to implement it but I had an error that 'ERROR:  GEOSIntersects: TopologyException: side location conflict at 13.5274576 52.423403700000001
SQL state: XX000'

Comment: or even this if the problem does not go away (workaround to make the query run): `SELECT   
  ST_Intersection(ST_MakeValid(r.geom),o.buffer) AS intersection,
  ST_Area(ST_Intersection(ST_MakeValid(r.geom),o.buffer))/ST_Area(r.geom)*100
FROM residential r, operations o
WHERE ST_Intersects(o.buffer,ST_MakeValid(r.geom));` @Aravinth

Comment: @Aravinth start first with a `LIMIT` to see if it works, then use `EXPLAIN` to see if the index is being used at all.

Comment: If I use the LIMIT it works, I tried to use the Explain but the Index is not used while doing the query. what can be done to use the index, I have tried to rectify it but ended of without any progress.

Comment: @Aravinth add query and the result of explain to your question, otherwise there is no way we can give you a decent suggestion.

Comment: @Aravinth you using an equal operator between an integer an a geometry `geom = 45`. You don't have to be sorry.. we all started from the beginning one day :) But as you can see, a question about "overlap proportion" can quickly be deviated to invalid geometries, how to create a fiddle and using explain. It is absolutely fine to ask, but keeping the conversation very long sort of makes the whole post incomprehensible for other users. So, I suggest you to first get familiar with creating a fiddle and ask another question about performance, otherwise it will never ends here. Happy coding :)

Comment: I have added the fiddle, the calculated percentage of the polygon within the buffer is not added into the table. Kindly have a look.

Comment: @Aravinth is this what you're looking for? In the end I corrected the `update` query https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=db0feeb2b03e71dcebfaa8c77685cfa9

Comment: Yes, this is the expected result. Thank you for the help and for clarifying the concept.

Comment: @Aravinth great! +1 for the fiddle