# Problem with ST_AREA regarding coordinate system

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I want to select all polygons with area more than 350 square kilometers from my initial polygons and tried ST_Area. But my polygons are in WKID: 25832 (UTM 32N) and I read that ST_Area always calculates in WGS 84 (EPSG 4326)....

I tried it like this but did not work.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS projekt."Final_Selection";
CREATE TABLE projekt."Final_Selection" AS
SELECT (st_area/1000000), geom 
FROM projekt."New_Pot" WHERE st_area>350 ;
```

and like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS projekt."Final_Selection";
CREATE TABLE projekt."Final_Selection" AS
SELECT (st_area(ST_Transform(geom,25832)))/10000000, geom  
FROM projekt."New_Pot" WHERE st_area>350;
```

Does anyone have an advice for me? Thx in advance!

Comment: You have one too many zeros where you intend to divide by 1 million in the second example

Comment: True thank you!, but this doesnt solve my whole problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select geometries by their size in sqm use [`ST_Area`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Area.html) with `geography` instead of `geometry`:

> For geography types by default area is determined on a spheroid with units in square meters.

```
SELECT * FROM projekt."New_Pot"
WHERE ST_Area(ST_Transform(geom,4326)::geography) >= 350000
```

**Note**: keep in mind that using `ST_Area` in the `WHERE` clause might slow down your query significantly, as the area is being calculated in query time. If it isn't a one time query, consider creating an index with the area pre-calculated, e.g.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_geom ON projekt."New_Pot" (ST_Area(ST_Transform(geom,4326)::geography));
```

See also: [Calculate the percentage of polygon inside the buffer in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67894958/2275388)

In case you want to query polygons within a given radius: the easiest way would be to convert your geometry column to `geography` and from there use [`ST_DWithin`](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html), which will calculate the distance in metres when used with `geography` parameters:

```
SELECT * FROM projekt."New_Pot"
WHERE 
  ST_DWithin(
      ST_Transform(geom,4326)::geography, -- your geometry converted to geography
      ST_MakePoint(1,52)::geography,      -- a given point
      350000)                             -- a 350km buffer
```

Related post: [Getting all Buildings in range of 5 miles from specified coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51895472/2275388)